# select2.js maintain previously clicked items which results in remove more than one items on confirmation popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have one textbox in which i can add and remove items using `select2.js`. Now i have one requirement that when i remove item from textbox, it should ask for some confirmation message.

For that i need to make a change in `unselect()` method of `select2.js`. Below is the code in which i have made change.

```
unselect: function (b) {
    var $curelm = this;
    var d = "", e= "", c = "";
    confirmpopup("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to remove this Tag?", function (confirm) {   //  <-- Here i have added confirmpopup code
        if (confirm) {
            c = $curelm.getVal();
            if (b = b.closest(".select2-search-choice"), 0 === b.length) throw "Invalid argument: " + b + ". Must be .select2-search-choice";
            if (d = b.data("select2-data")) {
                var f = a.Event("select2-removing");
                if (f.val = $curelm.id(d), f.choice = d, $curelm.opts.element.trigger(f), f.isDefaultPrevented()) return !1;
                for (;
                    (e = p($curelm.id(d), c)) >= 0;) c.splice(e, 1), $curelm.setVal(c), $curelm.select && $curelm.postprocessResults();
                return b.remove(), $curelm.opts.element.trigger({
                    type: "select2-removed",
                    val: $curelm.id(d),
                    choice: d
                }), $curelm.triggerChange({
                    removed: d
                }), !0
            }
        }
    });
},
```

I have prepare one **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ro0fq28/3/)** to show you my problem.

When i click on `"x"`(Remove sign) in the box, it'll open one confirm popup and in that popup if i click on `"Yes"` button then it'll perfectly remove item from the box and when i click on `"No"` button, it'll not remove item. Upto now everything is fine. Problem is arise now, when second time i click on `"x"` in the box and click on `"Yes"` button then it'll remove 2 items from the box rather than remove only selected items. I don't know why, but it'll maintain previous clicked items history(**I guess**).

Can any one point out what i have made wrong in the above code ?

To generate the issue in **JS Fiddle** follow below steps:

- Select more than two items.
- Click on `"x"` button on selected item and in confirm popup click on `"No"` button.
- Now again click on `"x"` button on another item and now click on `"Yes"` button on confirm popup.
- It'll remove two items rather than only selected one.

> > **NOTE:** I have added the whole `select2.js` code in JS Fiddle rather than add it in external link because i have made change in its `unselect` method.

Comment: You should really be catching the `select2:unselecting` event instead of modifying the core code for this. That event can be prevented, which appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: but i am using Select 2 Version: 3.5.0 and here is not this 'unselecting ' function or event in this version. but now my problem is resolve. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution after doing some deep digging in my code. The problem in `confirmpopup()` function. When i click on item to remove from select2 box at that time i have registered click event for `"Yes"` button. Then again i click on another item to remove from select2 box and again `"Yes"` and `"No"` button event registered of confirm popup in DOM. So this is the reason `"Yes"` button click event called 2 times.

So to overcome to this problem, i have to first **unbind** click event using [`.Off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method in the code like below.

```
function confirmpopup(title, message, callbackfunc) {
    $('#errorlabel').text(title);
    $('#popupmessage').text(message);
    $('#modelconfirm').show();

    $('#btnyes').off('click'); // <-- Solution is here

    $('#btnyes').on('click', function () {
        $('#modelconfirm').hide();
        callbackfunc();
    });

    $('#btnno, .close').on('click', function () {
        $('#modelconfirm').hide();
    });

}
```